# How to continually ask for user input for as many times as an int is holding?

Tags: c++

(NEW to c++, be nice)

I want to be able to ask the user to enter students' name for as many students as they said were in the list. So basically, I want to use an integer for the amount of times a question is asked.

(Yes, I saw a similar question for python but I don't know how I would apply that to c++.)

I know it involves a while loop. I know how to increment. I've set up a while loop, and all I need is the correct condition for it.

```cpp
//Num_Students equals the number of students the user has.
//Students_List equals the student number that I am asking for. Such as
//Student 1, and so on 
//s1 is a string that holds the name of the student. 

while (Num_Students =) {
  Students_List = 1;
  cout << "Enter the full name of student " << Students_List << " >";
  cin >> s1;
  Students_List++;
}
```

I want the output to be like so:

Enter the full name of student 1 > beep

Enter the full name of student 2 > bop

Enter the full name of student 3 > boop

and so on.

Comment: You do know `Students_List` is reset to `1` at the beginning of each loop? Also, you never use `Num_Students` in your loop?

Comment: I did not know that! Thanks for bringing it to my attention. I didn't want `Students_List` to start at 0, so I thought I needed to start it at 1 manually. As for `Num_Students`, I don't need to output what the exact number is, so there's no need for it to be declared elsewhere, i suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int Students_List = 1;
string s1;

while (Num_Students) {
    cout << "Enter the full name of student " << Students_List << " >";
    getline(cin, s1);
    Students_List++;
    Num_Students--;
}
```

where `Num_Students` is initialised to the number of students. `std::getline` reads from the input stream until end of line including any spaces. Note that `Students_List` has to be initialised before the loop, otherwise it gets reset to 1 each time the loop is executed.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try this out.

Answer (score 0):

You have options. You can either check for `EOF` but it wouldn't work here. You could also predefine a symbol for which your program would exit. As in, inputting `exit` will terminate your program. You could check the below program for help.

```
string s1("");
int Students_List = 1;
while (s1.compare("exit")) {
  cout << "Enter the full name of student " << Students_List << " >";
  cin >> s1;
  Students_List++;
}
```

I used  [string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/).

Comment: It's unclear, but I think there are `Num_Students` they want to take input on. So it could be `Students_List = 0;` then `while (Students_List < Num_Students) {...}` and only increment `Students_List` on successful input? I'll let you make that call.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah I just shot at the moon :) How can I make this answer better? I'm new to answering as well :)

Comment: I think it is complete based on the information given. You can always try and clarify if `Num_Students` has already been filled -- that way at least you will know what you are shooting at. I looks like that is the case from the comments above the original code -- but it is far from conclusive.